# Remove duplicate values in django forloop

Tags: django, django-templates

i have some dates in a list and I want to display all days in the list using forloop at Django template. what I want is to remove duplicate days in it.
here is the sample code

```
{% for part_time_day in part_time %}   
    {{part_time_day.start_time|date:"D"}},
{% endfor%}
```

it will display all the days like "Sun, Mon, Fri, Sun" etc but I want to remove duplicate days so one day can display only once

Comment: You better do this on the view side and pass ready to use data to the template.

Comment: I did already from views but there are some issues with date

Answer (score 0):

Django template has a [ifchanged](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) tag:

```
{% for part_time_day in part_time %}   
   {% ifchanged %} {{part_time_day.start_time|date:"D"}}{% endifchanged %},
{% endfor%}
```

It looks if the content has changed from previous iteration. So it will work better if you have ordered by start_time before.